# either + singular + 'have' or 'has'?

Tags: verb-agreement

Is it legal to use **has** in the following question?

> Would you tell me please whether either my friend Joey or me **has** to visit the manager tomorrow?

Or, instead, should I use **have** rather than **has**?

Answer (score 3):

I think that '*either*' here is being used in the sense that it is Joey, or 'me' (not both). So, the proper conjugation of the verb *to have* would be *has*.

You would generally use plural when you have '*either of*', for example:

> Would you tell me please whether either of us have to visit the manager tomorrow?

Comment: Jerry, welcome and +1. I like the disjunctive argument, in which one excludes the other. Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks Carlo :) I was browsing about the different SE and found this one, thinking I could learn some things myself. Also, nicely spotted for the _me_ vs _I_ part.

Comment: However, Jerry, if either is the subject of the clause "either of us have to visit the manager tomorrow?", as is, you should use *has*, not *have*. Why do you say that we have to use *have* there? Please, explain. Thank you.

Comment: In other terms, shouldn't "either" as a subject take a singular verb?

Comment: @Carlo_R. There's no straightforward rule; _either_ can be singular or plural depending on the situation. In my example, _either of us_ has a plural component 'us'. This goes the same way with _either of them_, _either of the students_, etc. _either_ gets singular when it's clear it's part of a singular phrase or by itself, e.g. "_Either_ is fine.", "_Either one_ will do." Even with these though, you might be finding differences among speakers.

Comment: I can't use US, because how the manager will know which employee I will go with ? I am working with 50000 employee at the same company, I want to ask the manager that I want to visit her with Joey, Just Joey, how please?

Comment: @Jerry. I disagree with the second part of your answer, and with parts of your comment reply to Carlo. *either of us* is the same as *one of us* - both are **singular**, so it's *one of us has to visit* or *either of us has to visit*. Only **one person** is visiting. Same as *Fred or Mike has to visit*.

Comment: @Smolina. Now I'm confused as to what you are trying to say. From your question I thought you mean (1) Joey visits the manager, OR (2) You visit the manager. From your recent comment, you seem to be saying it's (3) Joey AND you visit, OR (4) Joey visits alone.  Please clarify.

Comment: @TrevorD Actually, _either of us_ is **not** the same as _one of us_. It's actually _one, or the other, or both of us_. Because of this, going for plural is more natural. I already warned that it might be different among speakers. For example: _The are fields on either sides of the road_ for me means on both sides.

Comment: @SmolinaFezaphitsh I'm not telling you to us _us_. I'm telling you to use _either my friend Joey or me has_.

Comment: @Jerry We have to agree to disagree! From the references I've looked at (and the way I've understood it for the past 50+ years) "either of us" means one of us, but not both. FreeDictionary (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/either) has "either: one or the other (of two) ... Usage: Either is followed by a singular verb in good usage: either is good; either of these books is useful." ODO (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/either?q=either) has "either side of the road" (not "sides" plural) meaning "each side of the road". ("Each" is singular".)

Comment: @TrevorD I agreed to disagree in my answer _itself_. Now, I said that there's no single meaning. Take FreeDictionary: **1st either** _adj. One and the other; each: rings on either hand_ **2nd either** _det. both one and the other there were ladies at either end of the table_ **3rd either** _each of two; the one and the other: There are trees on either side of the river._ **Oxford** _det. there were no children of either marriage_ (Can't be one, otherwise this sentence doesn't make any sense) **2** _det. each of two:
the road was straight, with fields on either side_ (each of two implies both).

Comment: @Jerry Come on  you guys; Trevor is saying one thing and you, Jerry, are saying another: Either x or y=singular. One and the other is completely different. Either of us and one of us are singular.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your sentence is valid English where you use "me":

> either my friend Joey or **me** has to visit ...
>
> either my friend Joey or **I** has to visit ...

If I'm correct we should answer in reference the **I** version, and, if so, the use of **has** sounds awkward (third person) after **I** (first person).

So use **have**, but do not generalize the argument I proposed because sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are theoretically correct that it should be *I* rather than *me*, but I think most people (at least in UK usage) would say *either Joey or me ...*. What might be better is to rephrase it, e.g. *Joey has to visit the manager tomorrow, or I have to.*

Comment: I agree with TrevorD. But the fact is many people say: Either x or me, but in any case, the verb would be in the singular.

Comment: Its Valid English. It's merely invalid latin, but English isn't Latin. https://newrepublic.com/article/77732/grammar-puss-steven-pinker-language-william-safire

Answer (score -1):

*Every of you is wrong*

for instance in the first case

1. Would you please tell me whether(if) either of my friends, Joey or I have to visit the manager tomorrow?

you take as reference or subject agreement the one that is closer to the conjunction "or" in this case is have

2. Would you tell me please whether either of us has to visit the manager tomorrow?

in this case as the first one we have an exception anytime we have each, every, and either or neither we use the verb in singular in this case "has" rather than have which would have more sense at first but it's grammatically incorrect.

3. either my friend Joey or 
   I(me) have(has) to visit ... We use I instead of me because it's not a comparison and there is no a verb either. plus the verb have cuz' we take the closest one since the rule says.

the right question is

Would you tell me please whether either of my friends Joey or I have to visit the manager tomorrow? aslo we lack another friend to use either Joeu and who else??? .

Alex O'connor Msc.on Foreign Languages
I am irish

Comment: This seems to be seriously garbled -- perhaps you were posting from a cranky smartphone?